# Sharing - social buttons in websites

Tags: social-networking

I want to implement social buttons in my website. What is the best script choice according to your experience?

I found this: http://www.addthis.com/

Is it a long way to do a simple thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to insert the generated block code 
anywhere you want the buttons to show up in your document. For
a pure html page this would be extremely simple (cut and paste).

For a MVC or serverside generated website it might be a little
more tricky, but you'd just have to paste the same code in your
view, and maybe call a helper to include

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4f904e27168d5473"></script>`

in the head of your document, or inline with the rest of your code. 
I guess it really depends on how your website is set up.

I'd rate it from extremely easy to slightly moderate.